# Concatenating a variable as the jQuery val() argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I'm trying to set the value attribute of an input (a hidden input in a form) using the jQuery val() function. My idea was to concatenate the name of the variable and pass it as the argument to the function, but it doesn't work as I expected. The code in question is in the very last line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hash =  document.location.hash;
    var turismosSid = "1c0f8e3ec28b09f9487140930a0c0b73";
    var comercialesSid = "b31150acd348f775785b7c4a7398a3c6";

    if (hash === "#turismos") {
      activaTab("turismos");
      $('#js-sid').val(turismosSid);
    } else {
        activaTab("comerciales");
        $('#js-sid').val(comercialesSid);
    }

    $('#js-turismos-btn').on('click', function(){
        activaTab("turismos");
        document.location.hash = "turismos";
    });

    $('#js-comerciales-btn').on('click', function(){
        activaTab("comerciales");
        document.location.hash = "comerciales";
    });


    function activaTab(cual){
        $('#js-turismos-btn').addClass('bg-faded');
        $('#js-turismos').hide();
        $('#js-comerciales-btn').addClass('bg-faded');
        $('#js-comerciales').hide();

        $('#js-'+ cual + '-btn').removeClass('bg-faded');       
        $('#js-'+ cual).fadeIn(300);

        $('#js-sid').val(cual + "Sid");
    }

});
```

Rather than set the input's value to either of the variables turismosSid or comercialesSid, the function sets the value as the STRING turismosSid or comercialesSid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't reference variables through string concatenation*.

To do what you require you could put the `turismosSid` and `comercialesSid` values in to an object, as you can then reference the keys of that object using the string you concatenate together. Try this:

```
var sids = {
    turismosSid: "1c0f8e3ec28b09f9487140930a0c0b73",
    comercialesSid: "b31150acd348f775785b7c4a7398a3c6"
}

if (hash === "#turismos") {
    activaTab("turismos");
    $('#js-sid').val(sids.turismosSid);
} else {
    activaTab("comerciales");
    $('#js-sid').val(sids.comercialesSid);
}

// in activaTab()
$('#js-sid').val(sids[cual + "Sid"]);
```

*You could use `eval()` but it's considered about the worst thing you can possibly use in JS code, so I'm only including it in this note for the sake of completeness.